# Python program accessible from the internet

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, remote-access

I am busy writing a simple program in python which takes information from the serial port and displays a graph of this to the user. (It is basically a energy meter connected to the serial port and the python program should display the voltage, current and power curves.)

However, I would really like to make this program accessible from the internet (ie: one open's a web browser on the remote computer, types in the host pc's ip address and some port and you are confronted with the voltage, current and power curves)

I am very new to python and the whole object oriented programing language. Most of my programing was done in C# in the past.

Is there a relatively easy way to 'port' a python program to some form of web accessible program/script. Possibly by using it in conjunction with a Apache server running on the host machine?

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Even if it just points me in the right direction.

Thanks so much.

**EDIT:** I have now been playing around with CGI and Apache and I see that it is possible to execute .py files in Apache as cgi-binaries. However, when I attempted to execute my complete python program (containing a Qt form and many push buttons and combo boxes) the page just kept on loading forever, until it displayed a server timeout. Is this because I am using CGI and not FastCGI? or is it not possible to 'port' Qt framework to HTML? Should I rather create a new GUI framework out of HTML code?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: A tip to maybe not have to use full blown Apache, Python has a built in web server that can execute cgi binaries and may cover your needs; http://effbot.org/librarybook/cgihttpserver.htm

Comment: Same thing with WSGI, it has a built-in HTTP server.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (without compromising the security of your machine) is for the python script to read the serial data and create a couple of graphs every minute using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and write them to a place where a web server can find them as e.g. PNG files.

Then you need to create a webpage to display the graphs. For safety sake, it is best to make that a static page referencing the PNG files that your script made. Maybe put in some javastript to have the page [periodically refresh itself](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm).

Last but not least you need a webserver. I would suggest [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) for serving static content like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am considering using Django with Apache to run the python script and as you mentioned allow it to generate graphs the user can periodically refresh to obtained the latest readings of the meter. However, one last question though, would it be possible to port my gui for the Python script (made using Qt) to the web framework. Or should I construct a complete new gui in html?

Comment: You probably have to write the layout again in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of Python based frameworks for web development, for example Django: https://www.djangoproject.com. You can just develop a website in Python using Django and call your script from one of the views. And you can deploy your Django project with Apache: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Comment: Learning Django (a big framework able to do complicated Web sites) seems *way* overkill for a simple program like the one he suggested.

Comment: I think it's not that hard to get a basic Django project running. Plus, it has all the authentication / login business already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solutions seem to be CGI http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html and WSGI http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html

However, in both cases, I remind you that Web applications are known for their security problems. When you're a beginner, you typically open many security holes without even noticing it... but the bad guys on the Internet will notice. I suggest to at least protect the page with username/password.

Answer (score -1):

Why run and maintain your own webserver if you can run Python in Google App Engine. It is easy, free and almost 100% reliable. Google takes care of the webserver and you only have to build a Python application. 
The serial port client can send the data to your App engine application.

Here is a tutorial to get you started: http://aleatory.clientsideweb.net/2012/08/16/financial-charts-app-engine-tutorial-web-scraping/

Here is an Python example of sending data to App engine:  http://aleatory.clientsideweb.net/2012/08/16/financial-charts-app-engine-tutorial-web-scraping/

Comment: You should detail the difficult part: how a Google App Engine instance will have access to his serial port?

Comment: Maybe my answer was not clear for you. But ser1692282 who asked the question told us he is already building a Python applcation to read the serial data. This Python application has to send the data to app engine (see my answer). Here is a example: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-python/yzKimNqs4Es